# What does "First Look Companies" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Montgomery Summit occurs each year at the start of March. This year, it was held March 8-9, offering participation from **first look companies**, emerging firms, and growth businesses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about a nonce usage which is defined at the source, and which has no special meaning outside of this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Montgomery site](http://www.montgomerysummit.com/selection/) clarify, first look refers to private companies that have already raised seed capital and have revenues of less than 10 million  dollars.

FIRST LOOK:

> Raised a seed or series A round
>
> Annual revenue of less than $10M